# Needing help setting up Course to Role display in Access DB

Tags: vba, ms-access

An example of what i am trying to do. I am wanting to display on my Form in either a text box or list box, the courses a user needs to take after assigning the roles they need to perform their duties. I have a Table (tbl_GRC_Master_Roles_List) and it lists out all the roles in one column then in the 6 other columns are the 6 different courses. Each role requires (Course1), for the other (Course2) - (Course6) it varies. example:

```
(Role-A) needs (Course1), (Course2), (Course5), (Course6)
(Role-B) needs (Course1), (Course4), (Course6)
(Role-C) needs (Course1), (Course2), (Course3), (Course4), (Course5)
(Role-D) needs (Course1)
```

and so on and so forth for all the roles listed in the table.

When i am on the Form that i am able to select the role and assign them to the user i would like to display the courses in a text box or list box not sure which is easier or best practice, for the selected roles. The users get multiple roles assigned. So i don't want it to duplicate the courses in the display. I am just not sure how to accomplish this. Any ideas would be helpful to get me started. 
my table (tbl_GRC_Master_Roles_List) is setup as follows:

```
(ID) (RoleName) (Course1) (Course2) (Course3) (Course4) (Course5) (Course6)
```

When i assign a user roles it gets appended to a table (tbl_Assigned_Roles) its setup as follows:

```
(ID) (UserEmail) (RoleName)
```

Could i use a SQL statement in a Listbox to get this data?

Comment: As the very first step, learn how to _normalise a database_. Courses should go to a child table of Roles.

Comment: What purpose would listbox serve? Each course field could be a column of listbox. If you want courses vertical, then normalize data structure or use a UNION query to rearrange fields. Not clear what you are trying to accomplish and really need to rethink data schema.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. i will take it back to the drawing board.

Comment: I do want to say thank you June7 for at least giving me some pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I took a step back and revised what I was trying to achieve. Now I just did a Role Search by using a combo box and for its Row Source a Select Query with all of the Roles & the Courses as columns by looking at (tbl_GRC_Master_Roles_List). Then I placed a text box below the combo box, I expanded it a bit so I could see all the courses displayed. When I Select a Role from the Combo Box it only displays the Courses for that Role in the text box. Below is the code im using in an On-Change Event on the Combo Box:

```
Private Sub cbo_SearchList_Change()
Me.txtCourseList.Value = Me.cbo_SearchList.Column(2) & _
                vbNewLine & _
                Me.cbo_SearchList.Column(3) & _
                vbNewLine & _
                Me.cbo_SearchList.Column(4) & _
                vbNewLine & _
                Me.cbo_SearchList.Column(5) & _
                vbNewLine & _
                Me.cbo_SearchList.Column(6) & _
                vbNewLine & _
                Me.cbo_SearchList.Column(7) & _
                vbNewLine & _
                Me.cbo_SearchList.Column(8) & _
                vbNewLine & _
                Me.cbo_SearchList.Column(9) & _
                vbNewLine & _
                Me.cbo_SearchList.Column(10) & _
                vbNewLine & _
                Me.cbo_SearchList.Column(11) & _
                vbNewLine & _
                Me.cbo_SearchList.Column(12)
Me.txtCourseList.Requery
End Sub
```

This is what resolved my issue I hope it helps others. Sometimes simple is better. Thanks.